# Ubuntu Software Center: Delete license terms file

Tags: apt, software-center

I am trying to install a package and during installation I accidentally declined the license terms, terminating the installation.  Now when I try to install the same program I instantly get a "Declined License for XXXX" message pop up.  It's definitely not tied to the package since I have tried re-downloading new versions of the package.

Problem:

- Where can I find the license term files for programs in Ubuntu Software Center?

Comment: What was that package?

Comment: Deleting the license terms file won't help. You'll have to reconfigure the package or change thedebconf selection.

Comment: Thanks guys.  It's a internal workplace package so it's not publicly searchable.  muru, where can I go and change the debconf selection, and what should I change it to?